# Перевод из 16 в 2 систему счисления

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

У нас есть массив с закодированным в нем двоичным кодом.

```
byte alphabet[4][7] =
{
    {0x4,0xA,0x11,0x11,0x1F,0x11,0x11},
    {0x1E,0x11,0x11,0x1E,0x11,0x11,0x1E},
    {0xE,0x11,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x11,0xE},
    {0x1C,0x12,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x12,0x1C}
};
```

Тип массива можно изменить, т.к. я растерялся что нужно делать вообще. Код на С++ есть, но на ArduinoIDE он не работает. Вернемся к разбору. Каждый элемент массива представляет собой строку в двоичном коде. Это сделано для экономии памяти.(Возможно я и не прав) Для большего понимания прикрепляю фотографию. Она соответствует первой (Нулевой) строке массива. Желтым обозначается 1. Красным 0. Черным границы, которые не учавствуют в массиве, который описан выше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно преобразовать элемент массива, чтобы получить строку 1 и 0 для добавления в int массив? К примеру в этот:

```
int Mask[7][30] = {
{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
{0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
{1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
{1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
{1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
{1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},
{1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0}
};
```

Comment: используешь `& 1`, получаешь бит, затем сдвигаешь вправо на один бит `>> 1`, и повторяешь 5 раз. Биты нужно перевернуть потом или сразу.

Comment: Я не совсе понимаю как это работает, если честно)

Comment: Начнем с простого: понимаешь почему 0x4 обозначает желтую точку посередине?

Comment: Да, именно я это делал. Вернее кодировал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получилось что-то подобное, отступ между буквами есть (`LETTER_MARGIN`):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#define LETTER_WIDTH 5
#define LETTER_HEIGHT 7
#define LETTER_MARGIN 1

int main() {

    char alphabet[][LETTER_HEIGHT] = {
        {0x04,0x0A,0x11,0x11,0x1F,0x11,0x11}, // A
        {0x1E,0x11,0x11,0x1E,0x11,0x11,0x1E}, // B
        {0x0E,0x11,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x11,0x0E}, // C
        {0x1C,0x12,0x11,0x11,0x11,0x12,0x1C}, // D
        {0x11,0x11,0x11,0x13,0x15,0x19,0x11}, // И
        {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}, // empty
    };
    std::map<int, int> ma = { {'A', 0}, {'B', 1}, {'C', 2}, {'D', 3}, {'И', 4}, {' ', 5} };

    const int mytext[] = {'A', 'B', ' ', 'И', ' ',  'C', 'D'};
    int mytextSize = sizeof(mytext) / sizeof(mytext[0]);

    int outa[LETTER_HEIGHT][mytextSize * (LETTER_WIDTH + LETTER_MARGIN)];

    for (int i = 0; i < mytextSize; ++i) {
        int ch = ma[mytext[i]];
        int x = i * (LETTER_WIDTH + LETTER_MARGIN);
        for (int j = 0; j < LETTER_HEIGHT; ++j) {
            char c = alphabet[ch][j];
            for (int k = 0; k < LETTER_WIDTH; ++k) {
                outa[j][x + LETTER_WIDTH - k - 1] = c & 1;
                c >>= 1;
            }
        }
        // right margin
        for (int k = 0; k < LETTER_MARGIN; ++k) {
            for (int j = 0; j < LETTER_HEIGHT; ++j) {
                outa[j][x + LETTER_WIDTH + k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // output
    for (int j = 0; j < LETTER_HEIGHT; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mytextSize * (LETTER_WIDTH + LETTER_MARGIN); ++i) {
            std::cout << outa[j][i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Выводит:

```
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Правда, отступ можно брать из буквы, увеличив ширину символа на один, но тогда отступ будет слева.

Comment: Благодарю. Очень сильно выручил.

Comment: А с русскими как иметь дело? 
Выдает вот такую ошибку:
'error: narrowing conversion of '53404' from 'int' to 'char' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]'

Comment: если хочется использовать русские буквы из unicode, то можно использовать std::map

Comment: @PluggaRose, обновил ответ.

Comment: Ещё раз благодарю.